# overview of algorithms for AI, navigation, mapping, pathfinding

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, robotics

I want to begin with the topic of artificial intelligence and autonomous robots. What book (or webpage?) do you recommend to get an overview of nowadays approaches in this area? I'd like to get hold of algorithms being used, to know their pros cons etc. 
I know there are many threads here covering this subject, but what I find in discussions are particular algorithms and some references to them. I'd like to have a source which gives an overview of approaches, so that I can better imagine whole area of activity. 
Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: This is such a huge question. Do an amazon search, and look for ones described as for beginners. You do not even specify your background (do you have a college degree?) I mean somebody could point you anywhere from "AI for Dummies" to advanced papers written on the subjects in academic journals.

Comment: @thatidiotguy ok, I will be more specific. I'm studying now, my background spans from mechanics, controlling, to programming. Although I'm not an informatician or devoted programmer, I want to learn algorithms for motion and to programm them. Important for me is to have also some bit of background behind the code, so that I physically know what I'm programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your topics:

> Mark De Berg: Computational Geometry, Chapter 13: Robot Motion
>   Planning

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article about AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_inteligence) is a good place to start. Remember to look at the "See also", "References", "Further reading" and "External links" sections at the end of each article. This will help you start with the broad topic of AI and will guide you to more detailed articles about specific algorithms and so on.